# Removing lines containing encoding errors in a text file

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8, grep

I must warn you I'm a beginner. I have a text file in which some lines contain encoding errors. By "error", this is what I get when parsing the file in my linux console (question marks instead of characters):

[image: encoding error]
I want to remove every line showing those "question marks". I tried to grep -v the problematic character, but it doesn't work. The file itself is UTF8 and I guess some of the lines come from texts encoded in another format. I know I could find a way to reconvert them properly, but I just want them gone for now.

Do you have any ideas about how I could do this please?

PS: Some lines contain diacritics which are displayed fine. The "strings" command seems to remove too many "good" lines.

Comment: Have you tried `dos2unix`? http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1377/ for example

Comment: It says it is a binary file and won't work on it.

Comment: Mmmm I think I posted too fast. `dos2unix` solves new lines issues, but I think it does not solve these encoding issues. Let's wait for someone with more knowledge to answer :)

Comment: Alright, thanks for having a look fedorqui !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) on character encodings other than ANSI you must check 2 things:

1. Is the file really encoded in `X`? (`X` being UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM in your case. You could be trying to read UTF-8 WITH BOM, UTF-16, latin-1, etc. as UTF-8, and that would be the problem). Try reading in (not converting to) other encodings and see if any of them fits.
2. Is your locale or text editor set to read the file as UTF-8? If not, that may be the problem. Check for support and figure out how to change the setting. In linux try [locale](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_locale.htm) and [setlocale](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_setlocale.htm) commands to check and set it properly.

I like how [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for windows (which also runs perfectly in linux using wine) lets you set any encoding you want to read the file without trying to convert it (of course if you set any other than the one the file is encoded in you will only see those weird characters), and also has a different option which allows you to convert it from one encoding to another. That has been pretty useful to me.

If you are a beginner you may be interested in this [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). It explains briefly and clearly the whats, whys and hows of character encoding.

**[EDIT]** If the above fails, even windows-1252 and such ANSI encodings, I've just learned [here](http://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/un010011/) how to remove non-ascii characters using `tr` unix command, turning it into ASCII (but be aware information on extra characters is lost in this output and there is no coming back, so keep the input file just in case you find a better fix):

```
 tr -cd '\11\12\40-\176' < $INPUT_FILE > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

or, if you want to get rid of the whole line:

```
 grep -v -P "[^\11\12\40-\176]" $INPUT_FILE > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

**[EDIT 2]** This answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23361) gives a pretty good guess of what could be happening if none of the encodings work on your file (Unfortunately the only straight forward solution seems to be removing those problematic characters).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer ! I tried to change the encoding in Kwrite to read those mysterious characters. (UTF16, ISO etc.). I did them all. It doesn't change anything. That's why I'm looking for a way to just remove those lines with sed or grep.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Sure there must be one encoding that fits. I'm not familiar on how kwrite encoding settings work, but it may be trying to convert the file instead of using a different encoding to read it. There aren't that many options to try out if you know which region/language your file comes from. There are also a few windows charsets that may give you some trouble in linux, that's why I suggested notepad++ wich can run in wine if you don't have access to a windows machine.

Comment: This is perfect elcodedocle. But is there a way to delete the whole line, and not the characters with tr? I read the man page but couldn't find anything. Maybe there's a way to use the same expression with sed?

Comment: Try `grep -v -P "[^\11\12\40-\176]" infile > outfile` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works like a charm, exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a micro-Perl script like:

```
perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]+//g;' my_utf8_file.txt
```

Comment: Hello levif. Thanks for you answer. I've just tried it but this seems to remove all my accents (é,à etc.) and foreign characters as well (ex: я). I really don't know what's wrong. The file itself is not clearly utf8. By this I mean that it "should be" but that uchardet doesn't recognize the encoding at all.

Comment: Hi, can you give us a sample of your file (binary, of course) maybe using an hexadecimal format i.e. using hexdump or xxd if you have those tools ?

Comment: I saw a similar question: best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I checked it out and found some interesting results: l�ttam  is actually chinese, when decoded from utf16 to utf18: http://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php